# Batch Script - Export text file with infomraiton inside

Tags: batch-file

We are using RMTP for our video server, however we must create a SMIL (Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language) file per a video. If you have 1 video, no problem, however we have over 2000 +.

Below you can see a perfect SMIL file. This one is saved as video-test.smil

```
<smil>
<head>
<meta base="rtmp://xxx.cloudfront.net:1935/cfx/st/" />
</head>
<body>
<switch>
<video src="video-streaming/video-test-720.mp4" height="720" system-bitrate="2000000" width="1280" />
<video src="video-streaming/video-test-360.mp4" height="360" system-bitrate="800000" width="640" />
<video src="video-streaming/video-test-180.mp4" height="180" system-bitrate="300000" width="320"/>
</switch>
</body>
</smil>
```

My idea would be to make a batch script to do the following:

1. Read folder and create array with ONLY file names that have .MP4 extensions
2. Take first array and REPLACE "video-test" with name from first array
3. Export file with the same name from first part of array with .smil in a folder
4. Incremment array and repeat

Special feature would be to SKIP if file exsits.

Questions:

Can this even be done with a SCRIPT. Can someone help..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET targetdir=.
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b/a-d *.mp4') DO (
IF NOT EXIST %targetdir%\%%~ni.smil (
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=#" %%s IN (smiltemplate.txt) DO (
SET subs=%%t
IF DEFINED subs (ECHO %%s%%~ni%%t) ELSE (ECHO %%s)
)
) >%targetdir%\%%~ni.smil
)
```

save your perfect smil file as `smiltemplate.txt` - with the string `video-test` replaced by `#`

change the target directory to where you want to generate the `.smil`s and all's done!

Comment: STROKE A genius....!!!! Point.. Can I put the BAT file outside in another directory please... THANK YOU

Comment: Personally, I keep all my batch files in a directory called `BATCH` - 'though others prefer `BELFRY`. Then you need to add the directory to the `PATH` - `Settings>Control Panel>Advanced System Settings> Environment Variables button` Change the PATH to include the directory you've chosen - it's a semicolon-separated list. Then you can run a batch from anywhere (need to reboot). You'd need to include the directory path to the MP4s before the `*.mp4` like `c:\wherever\*.mp4` - and the same for `smiltemplate.txt` - but I'd be inclined to put `smiltemplate.txt` in the `BATCH` directory myself.